# How to remove unconvertable characters to ascii with SELECT in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I use a `CONVERT` function in my `SELECT`  statement in order to avert utf8 errors, but MySQL leaves question marks behind. Is there a way to convert the unconvertable characters to blank or space characters?

```
SELECT  MeetId,
        ResId,
        Special,
        CONVERT(proposal USING ascii) as Proposal,
        Analysis,
        Vote,
        Vote_for,
        Oppose,
        Discret,
        Abstain,
        gpVote %s
        FROM RESO
        WHERE RESO.MeetId = %s
```

As an example a typical result may have this in a field: `'The current issue ?A? is on the table '`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about just using `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT  
  REPLACE(CONVERT('§123' USING ascii), '?', '')
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7119).

Good luck.

Comment: Warning: If your database is encoded UTF8 and your field has strings with accents, this code will delete all the characters with accents.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful, sgeddes solution also removes all question marks(if exist) from your string!

For example :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT('§How are you?' USING ascii), '?', '')
```

Output will be : `How are you`